# Match any string that deviates at least one character from a given string

Tags: regex, pcre, regex-negation

I came across an issue where I needed to search for a number in a set of numbers where all start the same but end differently, like:

```
261234
261235
261236
261334
261244
261134 
260234
260134
260123
```

I may add that this was in a log file with some other gibberish which may complicate the issue. Say I want to match anything but `261134`.

My first instinct was to try `26[^1][^1][^3][^4]` but that matches none of the above because at some point each and anyone of the has one of the negated characters in the position I specified a negation for. 
The next closest thing to a solution i can think of is a mile long expression that would chain ors together like so:

```
26([^1]134|1[^1]34|11[^3]4|113[^4])
```

This however does not match everything yet. Instead I should do:

```
26([^1]\d{3}|\d[^1]\d\d|\d\d[^3]\d|\d{3}[^4])
```

I think I answered my own question by thinking about it more thoroughly while typing this, but I am still curious if there is a better solution as this was really unwieldy to figure out let alone type for such a simple problem. 
I could neither find a question about this nor a solution so I hope it is appropriate to leave this here to help others with a similar issue.

Comment: You could use a negative lookahead `\b26(?!1134)\d{4}\b`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a negated character class like `[^1]` expects a match and does match any character except char `1`

Using this pattern `26([^1]\d{3}|\d[^1]\d\d|\d\d[^3]\d|\d{3}[^4])` will match values like `26$333` or `261)33`

---

What you could do is to match 26 and use a negative lookahead `(?!` to assert what is directly on the right is not 1134. It that assertion succeeds, match 4 digits.

To prevent the digits being part of a larger word, you could use word boundaries `\b`

```
\b26(?!1134)\d{4}\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/E2FBLv/1)

Comment: I was unfamiliar with a "lookahead" but that's definitely superior! Thank you.

Comment: I just may not be able to cast votes yet since my rep is to low.